# Dates standardization in Google sheets using formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I have some raw data coming from a system. the issue is that system exports the dates using the US formating to be as M/D/YYYY meanwhile all my sheets using dates as DD/MM/YYYY or D/M/YYYY. i tried using this formula

```
=text(TO_DATE(DATEVALUE('Row Data'!A2)),"M/D/YYYY")
```

and then the date changes from e.g. 6/1/2021 to 1/6/2021 (here for June 2021) but after the date is becoming 1/6/2021 i think the other formulas are still reading the date as if it is already the same as 6/1/2021.

Here is a sheet that has some data that I'm struggling with [Dates Standardization](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12dDlM598rEcopFto2pdzOSIgSSOCHGsXVVwai8a9clM/edit#gid=0)

So any idea how to fix this mess?

Appreciate your help <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the formula you've already tried, does this work instead?

```
=date(regexextract(to_text('Row Data'!A2),".*\/(.*)"),regexreplace(to_text('Row Data'!A2),"\/.*",""),regexextract(regexextract(to_text('Row Data'!A2),"(.*)\/.*"),".*\/(.*)"))
```

Alternative:

```
=datevalue(regexreplace(to_text('Row Data'!A2),"(.|..)\/(.|..)\/(.*)","$2\/$1\/$3"))
```

Assuming you have US dates supplied in any of these formats:

```
M/D/YY
M/D/YYYY
MM/DD/YY
MM/DD/YYYY

M-D-YY
M-D-YYYY
MM-DD-YY
MM-DD-YYYY

M.D.YY
M.D.YYYY
MM.DD.YY
MM.DD.YYYY
```

To switch day with month, this will work relative to the example screengrab below:

```
=arrayformula(if(A1:A<>"", datevalue(regexreplace(to_text(A1:A),"(.|..)[\/\-\.](.|..)[\/\-\.](.*)","$2\/$1\/$3")),))
```

[image]

Comment: You don't know how you fixed my misery. it worked like charm thank you so much <3

Comment: since you know much about regex, i need somewhere to learn more about it using google sheets cuz most of the websites are talking about it with Python.

Comment: My initial formula wasn't working with double digits (10/12/2021). Updated. I'll see if I can simplify it. There will be others out there with better regex than me, but regexr.com is a helpful resource :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the further assistance with my question. it's very informative :) :)