# Cleaning and standardizing date information in Google Sheets for Formulas

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Is there a good way to standardize formatting throughout a google sheet when dates are being used inside of formulas.

I have come up with the following solution, but wonder if others have a more elegant solution?

```
ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(LEFT(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(I3:I),"^\S+")),5)))
```

My experience has with formulas using dates in Google Sheets is that it is unpredictable. Sometimes a formula works in one sheet, and I would expect it to work somewhere else, but it does not for an unobvious reason.

An answer provided in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68266885/dates-standardization-in-google-sheets-using-formulas) when you know the formatting is:

```
=arrayformula(if(A1:A<>"", datevalue(regexreplace(to_text(A1:A),"(.|..)[\/\-\.](.|..)[\/\-\.](.*)","$2\/$1\/$3")),))
```

My problem today was solved using the left() to resolve hidden time data

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
VLOOKUP(A3:A& left(DATEVALUE(C3:C),5), 
{Note!A3:A&note!B3:B, Note!E3:E}, 2, FALSE)))
```

`RegexReplace()` might be needed as DATEVALUE() might contain/display values such as /,-,.
`Left()` might be helpful because a 5 number string containing time data
`value()` could help convert something back into a value if that is needed
`DATEVALUE(text())` can help to standardize data into the same date formatting

An example of hidden data corrected for using LEFT(), `DATEVALUE("1/23/2012 8:10:30")` may display as 1/23/2012 but `value("1/23/2012 8:10:30")` is 40931.34063 but using the `left()` can help extract only the 5 numbers associated with the date.

I'm not sure if there is a usecase for To_Text() to be used here prior to converting to date. For example, `VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(LEFT(DATEVALUE(text(ToTEXT(A3),"mm/dd/yyyy")),5),"\D",""))`

Knowing where some of the other pitfalls lie might help to better have an answer to this question. If there is a more elegant solution than this:

```
VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(LEFT(DATEVALUE(text(A3,"mm/dd/yyyy")),5),"\D",""))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(LEFT(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(I3:I),"^\S+")),5)))
```

Comment: Please explain your formula.

Comment: read above in question